# Dynamic updation on listview is lost when i exit the activity

Tags: android, listview

I made an simple module in which i update my listview dynamically but my actual problem is when i exit the activity through back button and when comes back to same activity my dynamic updation on list view is lost.

So how can i persist those updation when i come back again to this activity.

Please show me some way to achieve this ..

Thanks,
Jalp.

Answer (score 0):

What is probably happening is that each time you come to back to it, it is recreated. If you're not saving the updates to the list in some kind of persistent storage, and then loading that storage on activity onCreate(), then you lose it.

You may also try declaring a android:launchMode="singleTop" attribute for your activity in the AndroidManifest.xml so that only one instance of the activity runs. If you do this, you may also have to implement the onNewIntent() method for the activity